# SVG CSS validation error: 'Property fill doesn't exist'

Tags: css, svg, w3c-validation

I've created an inline SVG, but the CSS validation comes up with errors:

> Property fill doesn't exist : #6be300
> Property stroke doesn't exist : #1d1d1d
> Property stroke-width doesn't exist : 5px

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```css
 svg {
   height: auto;
   width: 50%;
 }
 rect {
   fill: #6be300;
   stroke: #1d1d1d;
   stroke-width: 5px;
 }
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
  <title>blabla</title>
  <desc>blablabla</desc>

  <rect id="rect1" width="40" height="230" x="20" y="170" rx="10" />
  <rect id="rect2" width="40" height="300" x="60" y="100" rx="10" />
```

Comment: It's just working for me. http://codepen.io/joostdev/pen/yJJNbr

Comment: hi the above code which u gave working fine already

Comment: Ok! Thanks for letting me know! It doesn't validate with jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator, but I suppose it has to do with prefix.

Answer (score 4):

Choose "More Options" and then select a profile that includes SVG when you run the [validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator).

Comment: if you use any API like [`w3c-css`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/w3c-css) the option is `profile=css3svg`

Answer (score -4):

Solution:

```
<rect id="rect1" fill: #6be300; width="40" height="230" x="20" y="170" rx="10" />
<rect id="rect2" stroke="#1d1d1d" width="40" height="300" x="60" y="100" rx="10" />
```

Use that fill property and value in inline css and remove in external css. Solved!!!

Comment: <rect id="rect1" fill: #6be300; width="40" height="230" x="20" y="170" rx="10" />
<rect id="rect2" stroke="#1d1d1d" width="40" height="300" x="60" y="100" rx="10" />